# FFmpeg compilation warnings ATOMIC_VAR_INIT

Tags: c++, ffmpeg, clang, emscripten

While compiling ffmpeg (commit 1368b5a) with emscripten 3.1.17, there are two warnings, I would like the internet to help me better understand (I am not someone with deep c++ experience):

```
fftools/ffmpeg.c:339:41: warning: macro 'ATOMIC_VAR_INIT' has been marked as deprecated [-Wdeprecated-pragma]
static atomic_int transcode_init_done = ATOMIC_VAR_INIT(0);
                                        ^
/home/XYZ/ffmpeg-wasm/modules/emsdk/upstream/lib/clang/15.0.0/include/stdatomic.h:50:41: note: macro marked 'deprecated' here
#pragma clang deprecated(ATOMIC_VAR_INIT)
                                        ^
```

I understand [ATOMIC_VAR_INIT in this place](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/fftools/ffmpeg.c#L339) is deprecated, but by which tool (emscripten, clang)? And which party to be involved in the fix.

The other one is also interesting:

```
fftools/ffmpeg_filter.c:898:35: warning: floating-point comparison is always true; constant cannot be represented exactly in type 'float' [-Wliteral-range]
        if (audio_drift_threshold != 0.1)
            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ^  ~~~
```

The message and consequences are very clear. Whats not clear to me, is, [if this is](https://github.com/FFmpeg/FFmpeg/blob/master/fftools/ffmpeg_filter.c#L898) particular compiler issue, or code issue and which party to take care?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `ATOMIC_VAR_INIT` I found [this note](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/atomic/ATOMIC_VAR_INIT):

> This macro was a part of early draft design for C11 atomic types. It is not needed in C11, and is deprecated in C17 and removed in C23.

So, the deprecation was by the C standard (and [the C++ standard, though there it was deprecated in C++20](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/ATOMIC_VAR_INIT))

As for the floating point issue, the compiler states outright that:

> constant cannot be represented exactly in type 'float'

Which is entirely true. In binary every bit of a number represents a power of two. In integers it is fairly easy, the bits represent 1,2,4,8,16,32,64,... matching 2 to the power of 0,1,2,3,4,5,6,...

For example the integer: `0b100101` is (low bit it to the right): 1+4+32=37.

Floating points are roughly the same, but with a few more complications (which I will skip here). Basically the bits now represent *negative* powers of two: 0.5, 0.25, 0.125, 0.0625, ... But unfortunately this does not allow us to represent all possible decimal numbers (this is an impossible task, there are infinitely many decimal numbers between 0 and 1, and we only have a finite number of combinations with a finite number of bytes).

It turns out that `0.1` is one of the numbers that it is impossible to encode in binary floating point. Which makes sense as 0.1 is 1/2 * 1/5, and 1/5 cannot be represented as a power of 2.

If you do the math, you find that:

2^-4 + 2^-5 + 2^-8 + 2^-9 + 2^-12 + 2^-13 = 0.0999755859375

If you continue this sequence forever (skip two powers, add two powers, repeat), then you will get infinitely *close* to 0.1. But that is the best we can do.

If you want to do some more reading, then here is some links:

- [What Every Programmer Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://floating-point-gui.de/)
- [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)
- [IEEE-754 Floating Point Converter](https://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html)

Now, the part I am a bit unsure of is:

> warning: floating-point comparison is always true

Technically 0.1 should translate to some bit-pattern, and if you then throw a variable with that exact same bit pattern at the `!=` check, then the result should be `false`. But perhaps the compiler made an executive decision and just said: "Always `true`", because getting the exact bit pattern is super unlikely and fragile.

But whatever the case, and more importantly: `float != 0.1` is a really bad test. The links I put above elaborate on it much better than I can, but basically you don't ever want to test a floating point for strict equality - you always want to add an epsilon of some value (it depends on the numbers you compare).

For example: `abs(float - 0.1) < epsilon`.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed insight Frodyne